# asp.net How to pass parameter to usercontrol when its path is saved in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding a usercontol on the page and its path is saved in Database. Following code is working perfectly.

```
Control uc = Page.LoadControl(widgetItem["User control"]);
```

in the database the value is:

```
~/layouts/Dashboard/UserControls/News/SpecificNewsCategory.ascx
```

Now I want to pass a value to this usercontrol. Thought to use query string.  I did this:

```
 Control uc = Page.LoadControl(widgetItem["User control"]+ "?ParamConfig=" + "123");
```

But Now I get the exception:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The file '/layouts/Dashboard/UserControls/News/SpecificNewsCategory.ascx?ParamConfig=123' does not exist.
```

I need some suggestions how to tackle this issue? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can pass querystring parameters to a user control - it's not a URL you're passing into the `LoadControl` method, it's a (virtual) path. It doesn't create a separate HTTP request to the browser which could interpret the querystring parameters.

If you have properties of the user control that you want to set then you need to cast the control to the appropriate Type and set the properties like any other complex object. Your user control needs to expose these as public properties.